# React Native: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: react-native

I'm quite new to React Native and have a question.

I get this warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I've tried everything. Now I even have Math.random() as key and I still get the warning.

Home.js:

```js
return(

    
  <ScrollView style={styles.container}>

<StatusBar barStyle='light-content' />


<ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.image} imageStyle={styles.image2}>
    <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'rgba(249,249,249,1)' ]} locations={[.4, 1]}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          height: 400
        }} />
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.9} style={styles.topNews} onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('WebView')}>
      <Text style={styles.topCategoryText}>ITALIAN LEAGUE</Text>
      <Text style={styles.topTitleText}>Juventus legend: Ronaldo is natural to be criticized</Text>
      <Text style={styles.topSourceText}>CNN Sport</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      
    
    </ImageBackground>

    <View style={{marginHorizontal: 10, flex: 1}}><RNMasonryScrollView 
            colums='2' 
            columnStyle={{flexDirection: 'column'}} 
            oddColumnStyle={{flex: 1, marginRight:15, marginLeft:10}}
            evenColumnStyle={{flex:1,marginLeft:15}}
            >
      {[
            <NewsDetail Key='1' title="Papers: Salah eager for Barca move" category='LA LIGA' imageSrc='https://en.as.com/en/imagenes/2020/06/11/football/1591881357_315795_noticia_normal.jpg'/>,
            <NewsDetail Key='2' title="Man Utd struggles 'mentally impacting' Pogba, says France boss Deschamps" category='PREMIER LEAGUE' imageSrc='https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photo/2019/06/20/88784d96-ef4b-4414-8b59-517c15b162a5/MW1-EditorialLead-new.png'/>,
            <NewsDetail Key='3' title="Arsenal's complete player: The meteoric rise of Vivianne Miedema" category='PREMIER LEAGUE' imageSrc='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTupBTx2is9w3Z7pIhrorpPDMTFHmQhS1Ypmg&usqp=CAU'/>,
            <NewsDetail Key='4' title="Mourinho hit with suspension by UEFA" category='SERIE A' imageSrc='https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/football/2018/02/13/TELEMMGLPICT000153853426_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqwD2sfO9joeQ6RY-qlTATNB2cSHopZMn-aCc647VHTAY.jpeg'/>,
            <NewsDetail Key='5' title="'Ronaldo is definitely faster than me!' – Bolt" category='LA LIGA' imageSrc='https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photo/2018/08/10/bf1acdf0-7b10-4dfe-8844-06f0f18d5c38/2018-08-10T192712Z_1257041591_RC18CE142CA0_RTRMADP_3_SOCCER-ENGLAND-MUN-LEI.JPG'/>,
            <NewsDetail Key='6' title="Southgate admits to fears over Maguire's career" category='LIGUE 1' imageSrc='https://images.daznservices.com/di/library/GOAL/a8/c9/vivianne-miedema-goal-50-gfx_nuhcgkr4tthu1kyux2ymq4y4l.jpg?t=-1147520971&amp;quality=60&amp;w=1200'/>,
            ]}
    </RNMasonryScrollView></View>

  </ScrollView>
  

  )
```

NewsDetail.js

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';





const NewsDetail = (props) => {

    const random = Math.random()
    const ViewWidth = 157.5
    // const [imageSize, setImageSize] = useState({width: 0, height: 0});
    // const [viewSize, setViewSize] = useState({width: 0, height: 0});
    const [imageHeight, setHeight] = useState(0);

    const myUri = props.imageSrc;

    useEffect(() => {
        Image.getSize(myUri, (width, height) => {
        
            setHeight(height / (width / ViewWidth));
            
            
        
        });

    }, []) 

    if(imageHeight > 0){

        console.log(random)
        

        return (
            <View style={styles.newsDetail} key={`${random}`}>
                <Image
                resizeMode='cover'
                    style={{
                        width: ViewWidth, 
                        height: imageHeight, 
                        borderTopLeftRadius: 7, 
                        borderTopRightRadius: 7,
                        }} 
                    source={{ uri: myUri,}}
                />
                <Text style={styles.textOne}>{props.category}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textTwo}>{props.title}</Text>
    
            </View>)

    } else return null;

    
      
    
    

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({


    image:{
        
        width: '100%',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 7, 
        borderTopRightRadius: 7

    },
    newsDetail:{

         
        backgroundColor: "white",
        marginTop: 10,
        borderRadius: 7,
        opacity: 0.9,
    shadowColor: "grey",
    shadowRadius: 5,
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 0},
    shadowOpacity: 0.3
        

    },
    textOne:{
        fontSize: 10,
        color: '#7A7F82',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingBottom:3
    },
    textTwo:{
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#2D3041',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingBottom:10
    }


});

export default NewsDetail;
```

I dont know what to do. Any help? Also, is there any websites where I can pay to get quick help on questions I have about React Native? Similar to StackOverflow just you pay to get quick answers on all questions?

Comment: You get your answers pretty quick here if you can provide codes that we can help you with.

Comment: Try removing `key={}` from code

Comment: The attribute is `key` and not `Key` (notice the small lettering). Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper way to generate a list is to create an array of objects, then you use map to display. In your codes, it's almost correct. You should use key instead of Key.

```
const articles = [ 
{ id: 1, title: "Papers: Salah eager for Barca move", category: 'LA LIGA', imageSrc: 'https://en.as.com/en/imagenes/2020/06/11/football/1591881357_315795_noticia_normal.jpg' },
{id: '2', title: "Man Utd struggles 'mentally impacting' Pogba, says France boss Deschamps", category: 'PREMIER LEAGUE', imageSrc: 'https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photo/2019/06/20/88784d96-ef4b-4414-8b59-517c15b162a5/MW1-EditorialLead-new.png'},
{ id:'3',title: "Arsenal's complete player: The meteoric rise of Vivianne Miedema", category: 'PREMIER LEAGUE', imageSrc: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTupBTx2is9w3Z7pIhrorpPDMTFHmQhS1Ypmg&usqp=CAU'}]

<RNMasonryScrollView 
            colums='2' 
            columnStyle={{flexDirection: 'column'}} 
            oddColumnStyle={{flex: 1, marginRight:15, marginLeft:10}}
            evenColumnStyle={{flex:1,marginLeft:15}}
            >
      { articles.map((article) => {
          return <NewsDetail key={article.id} title={article.title} imageSrc={article.imageSrc} />
       })}
           
    </RNMasonryScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had to use the key attribute in NewsDetail, that's why I used "Key" as a prop to send it over. The more you learn.

Comment: the key is to prevent those items from being re-rendered each time, so it has to be unique and fix. It cannot be Math.random() when rendering.